# Characterizing Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$: $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function.

Given that $f$ is (infinitely) differentiable, it is clear that $f$ is a polynomial if and only if some higher derivative of $f$ vanishes. As far as I know, thanks to some clever Baire category argument, we can even weaken this (at least formally) to say that $f$ is a polynomial if and only if, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, all but finitely many of the pointwise derivatives $f^{(n)}(x)$ vanish.

What if we try to characterize polynomials for a larger class of functions, say the continuous ones?

A continuous $f$ is a polynomial if and only if...? Is there some result of this form that does not use derivatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answer your question in general.

Assume that $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ or
$\mathbb{C}$ and $V$ and $B$ are vector spaces over $F$ and $X$ is a
Banach spaces over $F$.

A function $a:V\rightarrow B$ is said to be additive provided
$a(x+y)=a(x)+a(y)$ for all $x, y\in V$; in this case it is easily
seen that $a(rx) =ra(x)$ for all $x\in V$ and all $r\in \mathbb{Q}$
[1].

If $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a:V^{k}\rightarrow B$, then we say that a
is $k$-additive provided it is additive in each variable; we say
that a is symmetric provided
$a(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{k})=a(y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{k})$ whenever
$x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{k}\in V$ and $(y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{k})$ is a
permutation of $(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{k})$.

If $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a:V^{k}\rightarrow B$ is symmetric and
$k$-additive, let $a^{\ast}(x)=a(x,x,...,x)$ for $x\in V$ is and
note that $a^{\ast}(rx)=r^{k}a(x)$ whenever $x\in V$ and $r\in
\mathbb{Q}$. Such a function $a^{\ast}$ will be called a
monomial function of degree $k$ (assuming $a^{\ast}\neq 0$).

A function $p:V\rightarrow B$ is called a generalized
polynomial} (GP) function of degree $m\in \mathbb{N}$ provided

there exist $a_{0}\in B$ and symmetric $k$-additive functions
$a_{k}:V^{k}\rightarrow B$ (for $1\leq k\leq m$) such that
$$p(x)=a_{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{k}^{\ast}(x)\ \ \ for\ all\ x\in V,$$
and $a^{\ast}_{m}\neq 0$. In this case
$$p(rx)=a_{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{m}r^{k}a_{k}^{\ast}(x)\ \ \ for\ all\ x\in V\ and\ r\in \mathbb{Q}.$$

Let $B^{V}$ denote the vector space (over $F$) consisting of all
maps from $V$ into $B$. For $h\in V$ define the linear
difference operator $\Delta_{h}$ on $B^{V}$ by
$$\Delta_{h}f(x)=f(x+h)-f(x)\ \ \ for\ all\ f\in B^{V} and\ x\in V.$$
Notice that these difference operators commute
($\Delta_{h_{1}}\Delta_{h_{2}}=\Delta_{h_{2}}\Delta_{h_{2}}$ for all
$h_{1},h_{2}\in V$) and if $h\in V$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then
$\Delta_{h}^{n}$--the $n$-th iterate of $\Delta_{h}$--satisfies
$$\Delta_{h}^{n}f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}(_{k}^{n})f(x+kh)\ \ \ for\ f\in B^{V}\ and\  x,h\in V.$$

The following theorem were proved by Mazur and Orlicz and in greater generality by Djokovi$\acute{c}$.

Theorem:

If $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $f:V\rightarrow B$, then the following are
equivalent.

$\Delta_{h}^{n}f(x)=0$ for all $x, h\in V$.

$\Delta_{h_{n}}...\Delta_{h_{1}}f(x)=0$ for all $x,h_{1},...,h_{n}\in V.$

$f$ is a GP function of degree at most $n-1$.

**Therefore:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, then the following are equivalent.

$\Delta_{h}^{n}f(x)=0$ for all $x, h\in \mathbb{R}$.

$f$ is a polynomial function of degree at most $n-1$. (note that a GP function that is continuous is a polynomial.)

*S‎. ‎Mazur and W‎. ‎Orlicz‎, ‎Grundlegende Eigenschaften der Polynomischen Operationen‎, ‎ Erst‎
‎Mitteilung‎, ‎Studia Math. 5(1934)‎, ‎50-68‎.*

*S‎. ‎Mazur and W‎. ‎Orlicz‎, ‎Grundlegende Eigenschaften der Polynomischen Operationen‎, ‎ Zweite‎
‎Mitteilung‎, ‎ibidem. 5(1934)‎, ‎179-189‎.*

*D‎. ‎$\check{Z}$‎. ‎Djokovi$\acute{c}$‎, ‎A representation theorem for $(X_{1}-1)(X_{2}-1) · · · (X_{n}-1)$ and its applications‎,
‎Ann‎. ‎Polon‎. ‎Math.  22(1969)‎, ‎189-198‎.*

Comment: That's pretty cool. But over $\mathbb{R}$ I note that the iterated operators are precisely what you get when you substitute the standard differential quotient definition of derivative into itself all over again, right?

Comment: @Mathgemini yes, It seems similar. Indeed when you have a polynomial for its differential you did not need basically to take limit. Converse, when for a continuous function if i didn't need basically to take limit for its differential, so it must be polynomial, as I write above.